# Eclipse 4.5.1. - DTP Plugin - bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime

Tags: java, database, eclipse, plugins, runtime

I am trying to install the DTP plugin for Eclipse on the most recent Eclipse version (4.5.1.), but I always get this error:

"bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime was not found.bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.12.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency"

I tried changing the preference settings, different versions of the plugin - nothing works.

Anybody any advice on how to fix this?

Best
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying the code requires version 3.12.0 of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` as a minimum - but the version in Eclipse 4.5.1 is only 3.11.1.

Version 3.12.0 of `org.eclipse.core.runtime` is in the development versions of Eclipse 4.6 so it looks like you are trying to install a version of DTP intended for Eclipse 4.6

Comment: I thought I had the newest Eclipse installed, but I guess Ill try to download some older DTP packages then, thanks